# Construct using a maximum area polygon given a number of sides and side lengths

Tags: python, math, geometry, polygon

I need some help with my approach for constructing an n sided polygon that maximizes area.

I have written the following code for a 4 sided polygon, given the side lengths as user input.

I am having trouble turning this into generic code for "any n sided polygon" (with the value of n and all lengths given as user input)

```py
import numpy as np
import math


def area_t1(a, b, c):
    s = (a + b + c) / 2
    return math.sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c))


side_lengths = []

for i in range(4):
    side = int(input("Enter the individual side length"))
    side_lengths.append(side)

z = side_lengths[0] + side_lengths[1]

if side_lengths[0] > side_lengths[1]:
    y = side_lengths[0] - side_lengths[1]
else:
    y = side_lengths[1] - side_lengths[0]

areas = []

for i in np.arange(y + 0.1, z, 0.0001):
    a1 = area_t1(side_lengths[0], i, side_lengths[1])
    a2 = area_t1(side_lengths[2], i, side_lengths[3])
    area = a1 + a2
    areas.append(area)

print(max(areas))
```

Comment: _I tried to do this but I am getting wrong output_ Show us what you tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, but remember to read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask): don't make people guess at what you did, or what code you wrote. (1) describe what you needed to do, (2) talk about what approach you thought would work for that, (3) show the code you wrote to implement that approach (4) talk about how that didn't do what you expected, and (5) talk about what you already (re)searched/debugged. Right now, your question is basically missing everything after step 1.

Comment: Start solving the problem for a triangle

Comment: This is a geometry problem first, and a programming problem second. So, start by forgetting about python and programming, and think about geometry instead. What do you think a maximum-area polygon will look like, given the list of side-lengths?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930607/maximum-area-enclosure-given-side-lengths looks like the same problem

Comment: I have edited my post so answer my question now?

Comment: please don't post AI generated code... and if it is even wrong just make no sense! 1) Use a proper indentation 2) does `area_t1` return really an area of a triangle with sides `a, b, c`?

Comment: I have shown you what I have actually tried and I do not understand why ai code does not make sense cause when you do not know where you start you would actually learn the code written by ai first take reference and get an idea of the approach what is wrong with that ???? and coming to the area you can check the area code is actually written by me not ai and it gives you correct answer you can check it is herons formula

Comment: Usually, the part where you already need to know programming in order to identify what is wrong with what a chatbot gives you, so using it as a way to _learn_ how to program requires an AI specifically designed for that purpose, not a general chat AI like GPT. However, as mentioned by cards and Rafal: first solve the case for a triangle, specifically (i.e. dedicate code that knows it's working with three points). Then solve the case for a rectangle, specifically. How does the triangle generalize to the rectangle? And: did you read the math post?

Comment: `Heron's formula` is an important information (I totally forgot about that) that is more important than mentioning AI code

Comment: For all of your info I created my account today just an hour ago so do not bang me saying how to post. I mean give tell me how to but not rashly

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to approach this problem ?

Comment: There is no rash, but also no artificial friendliness. There are posting guidelines, which you updated your post for, that's good, but the code you're showing does not seem to be your own code, and that's bad because that means that we can't see what _your_ level of programming is, and so can't write an answer appropriate to that level. The "real" answer is that maths post, which explains that you maximize area by inscribing a circle.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I actually wrote my second code for a 4 sided polygon but I do not know how to generalize it for any n sided polygon?? I must keep on adding an extra for loop for more sides if I have to modify the second code so any suggestions on how to generalize the second code??

Comment: Please fix that second code block: it's lacking indentation and spacing, so it's not valid Python code right now.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I understand what you are saying ok it is my bad that I posted  ai code but the second code is what I wrote on my own you can check that out.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the second code I mean while posting it i indented it like that as per the post guide lines . In my google colab the code is properly indented and it is working .

Comment: That's great but the code you're currently showing to other people, in this post, can't work. It's invalid code. So please hit [edit] and fix it so that it's real code. And in the process of editing, also remove the code you didn't write, because that's not helpful in clarifying your question. In effect, please reread the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) to understand _why_ you're being asked to do these things: you're not just asking for yourself, all posts on SO are for _everyone with the same problem_ so describing your problem in your post with [mcve] code is _super_ important.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ok I will edit. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans   So are you saying this is question has already been asked by someone?

Comment: Using an inductive approach I think the problem is underdeterminated (too many unknowns wrt equations) and no _exact_ value for the max area can be found. @Gayatri do you anything about the existence of such maximum value?

Comment: @cards   maximum area can be determined with the given data. I wrote a code (*my own code*) for that we will not get exact area but nearly correct area. but my code is only for 4 sided polygons.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this now that it's basically a normal question.